# Relationship between "cellsize" in ASCII format and area on a map in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-ascii-raster

I'm trying to import data into Arc in ASCII format, however, I have no idea what to use for the "cellsize" for the ASCII format of the data (the original data I have is in excel where each excel cell represents a grid/cell from a model output).

I need the "cellsize" to correspond to the actual area of the grid/cell from the model output on the map in ArcMap. The dimensions of the grid/cells from the model are 7000 meters X 7000 meters. How does this 7000 meters in ArcMap correspond to the value I enter for "cellsize" in ASCII format?

Comment: How are you "trying to import data into Arc in ASCII format"? i.e. what tool and parameter values are you using, and how does the result observed differ from what you are expecting?  Also, I note that you have not yet taken the [Tour] that introduces users to our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use the ASCII to Raster tool in the conversion toolbox?
If so, your ASCII file needs a header before tool execution.  The header listings are the number of columns, number of rows, the lower left x coordinate, the lower left y coordinate, and a cell size (7000), and a no data value (-9999 maybe)

NCOLS xxx

NROWS xxx

XLLCORNER xxx

YLLCORNER xxx

CELLSIZE xxx

NODATA_VALUE xxx

Comment: @GBC here is the link to [ASCII to Raster tool](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00120000002s000000) to help support your answer.

Comment: Yes, I have the header. I am wondering what to put for "cellsize" so that the cell/grid size from the model output that I have matches the actual area on a map in Arc.

Comment: Is the full extent of your data 7000 x 7000 meters or is each cell from your model 7000x7000?  If the cell is 7000x7000 then 7000 is the cell size in the header.  If the extent of the data is 7000 then the cell size is 7000/number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Can you import the ASCI grid as point shapefile? If so, you could try converting the point layer into a raster. You could also use the measure tool to determine the distance between points (just make sure you are in a projected CRS.)